# Sheet js xlsx Read date value return wrong date

Tags: reactjs, xlsx, sheetjs

I am trying to read excel data using sheetjs xlsx npm library. I am getting wrong date when i tried with chrome browser. If i use Firefox, the date value is correct. Can anyone help me to resolve this issue.

```
Eg: I am trying to read date from excel is : 2021-08-01
Result i am getting is : 2021-07-31


Code:
------
const wb = XLSX.read(bufferArray, { type: "buffer", dateNF: "YYYY-MM-DD", cellDates: true, cellNF: false, cellText: true });
const wsname = wb.SheetNames[0];
const ws = wb.Sheets[wsname];
const data = XLSX.utils.sheet_to_json(ws);
```

Answer (score 1):

***This is something to do with the specification of dates in Chrome and Firefox***

When parsing a date as a string without an explicit time, Chrome will default the Date object's time to midnight local time. Firefox will default it to midnight GMT.

Do have a look at the following issues for further details [Sheet js response](https://github.com/SheetJS/sheetjs/issues/718#issuecomment-748270662).

[image: Sheet js response]
[difference in dates github issue](https://github.com/SheetJS/sheetjs/issues/1918)

So basically the Dates will be converted based on the application used:

[image: Difference in chrome and Firefox]

As per my understanding, the result from both chrome and Node.Js will be the same.

One other thing to keep in mind is that

***Chrome gives you the time in UTC+0, while Firefox gives you the time in GMT+0530***

It is always a good practice to convert the dates to a common format and then pass it to the sheetJS module.